# Neo4j: getting the relationship count of each node in a collection

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

```
MATCH p=(a:Node)-[*2]->(b:Node{code:"12345"})
with DISTINCT filter(x in nodes(p) where x:Node)as q
RETURN q
```

This is giving me a collection (i believe) of a pair of nodes ("a" and "b"). I want to find the count of all the nodes directly connected to "a".

How do i do this?

Answer (score 1):

This should be nicer:

```
MATCH p=(a:Node)-[*2]->(b:Node{code:"12345"})
UNWIND nodes(p) as n
WHERE n:Node
RETURN n,size( (n)--() ) as degree
```

Answer (score 0):

This query counts the number of nodes 1 relationship away from `a`:

```
MATCH (a:Node)-[*2]->(:Node{code:"12345"})
MATCH (a)--(x)
RETURN COUNT(x)
```